# Extrude (vertex/edge/face) along axis?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I`m trying to extrude an edge from a simple plane(or box or any other simple object) but Ctrl+E in edit mode then dragging on the yellow handle just moves the extruded edge around without any restraints. I found something about Axis Locking which I couldn't get to work in 2.8. The same issue seems to exist when extruding faces and vertices.

The workaround I found via some tutorials: dragging out the edge then canceling before committing, then using the gizmo (W) to move in a certain direction. I`m sure that's not how it's done but tutorials and docs didn't yield anything useful on the matter (maybe bad search skills in which case I apologize in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>E</kbd>< to extrude followed by the axis you want to constrain to. So <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>would constrain to the X axis.

Alternatively <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and hold down the middle mouse button and that also constrains.

Comment: scratch that. I just reset my keymap settings and now it works even with industry standard keymap. not sure what overwrote that